# Webpack app (office add-in) fails to start when deployed to Azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, outlook-addin, webpack-dev-server, office-addins

I've set up an outlook add-in via the yeoman office add-in generator as detailed in the tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial

This is essentially a Node app which utilizes webpack. I am attempting to host this app on Azure App Service, however every time I deploy the app, I get the error shown below.

The app is set to run out of port 3000, which I have exposed in the app settings. However still no luck. Any thoughts on what the issue might be?

```
2019-04-15 04:26:53.591 ERROR - Container testaddin43984_0 for 
site testaddin43984 did not start within expected time limit. 
Elapsed time = 400.2035387 sec
2019-04-15 04:26:53.611 ERROR - Container testaddin43984_0 didn't 
respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See 
container logs for debugging.
2019-04-15 04:35:39.506 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-04-15 04:35:39.507 INFO  - docker run -d -p 31557:8080 --name 
testaddin43984_0 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.14 -e 
APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.14 -e 
WEBSITES_PORT=3000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=testaddin43984 -e 
WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=801899fe3bb51451491b9664dc3eb742fd693df437561cc840139a9f5c7dc0bb -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:10.14_1903081107
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, the issue is with the start script. The script is taking more time and it eventually times-out.

> 2019-04-15 04:26:53.591 ERROR - Container testaddin43984_0 for 
>   site testaddin43984 did not start within expected time limit.

Try to reduce the time taken by the `npm start` script in your project.
I use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to solve these kind of problems